# Keeping session id when getting source code from web page

Tags: c#, session-variables, webrequest

I'm making a C# windows form application that needs to parse data from an external site that requires me to log in.

First I send the POST data on the login page using a WebRequest. This works correctly as I can see the page source of a page that requires me to log in.

When I try to view the page source code of the data-page however, I'm logged out again as the session gets lost.

Is there any way of storing the PHPSESSID and re-using it in another request?

EDIT:

```
WebRequest _theRequest;
...
_theRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
_theRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

The property CookieContainer is not showing up in the intellisense list, anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign a [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx) and reuse the request object for subsequent requests.

Comment: It seems I can't use the CookieContainer property. I've added System.Net to the references list but it's still not showing up.

Comment: @geoffreydv, your request variable must be defined as a HttpWebRequest and not WebRequest if you want this property to show. Example: `var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();`.